# $\limsup$ and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I cant do this:

assume that $P(\limsup A_n)=1$ and $P(\liminf B_n)=1$. Prove that $ P(\limsup (A_n \cap B_n))=1$.

The most I get is that if $P(\liminf A_n)=1  $ this is right.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? I guess it's $P(\limsup_n (A_n\cap B_n))=1$.

Comment: maybe this helps  $\limsup A_n= \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \left( \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n \right)$ and $\liminf B_n = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{n \ge N} B_n\right)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not the best nor the shortest proof). By the definitions of $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ you have that $$\lim \sup (A_n\cap B_n):=\{x \in X: x \in A_n\cap B_n \text{ for infinitely many $n$}\}$$ From the given conditions you have that there exist two set of measure zero $N_A$ and $N_B$ such that $$x\in\lim\sup A_n=\{x \in X: x \in A_n\text{ for infinitely many $n$}\}$$ for all $x\in X\backslash N_A$ and $$x\in\lim\inf B_n=\{x \in X: x \in B_n \text{ finally for every $n$}\}$$ for all $x\in X\backslash N_B$. Then every $x\in X\backslash(N_A\cup N_B)$ (which is still a set of measure $1$) belongs to infinitely many $A_n$ and finally to every $B_n$. So it belongs to infinitely many sets of the form $A_n\cap B_n$ and thus it belongs to the set $$\lim \sup (A_n\cap B_n)$$ which proves that the measure of the latter set is still $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a homework question, I will only give two intermediate steps.

1. Notice that $\mathbb P(\limsup_nA_n\cap \liminf_n B_n)=1$.
2. Show that $\limsup_nA_n\cap \liminf_n B_n\subset\limsup_n(A_n\cap B_n)$.

Comment: I have problems with the second step, $lim sup A_n \cap lim in B_n \in lim sup A_n \cap lim sup B_n$ but now i know that  $lim sup(A_n \cap B_n) \in lim sup A_n \cap lim sup B_n$ not the contrary

Comment: Fix $x$ in the LHS: then $x\in B_k$ for $k$ large enough, and $x$ lie in infinitely many $A_n$'s, hence for infinitely many $k$, $x\in A_k\cap B_k$.

Comment: thanks!!it was not difficult , i guess I didnt actually understand the real meaning of lim sup and lim inf :)

Comment: Im told to say what happens if the condition on${B_n}$ is weakened to $P(lim sup B_n)=1$ I thought the example $A_1=\omega$ $A_2= 0$$ A_3=\omega$.. and $B_1= 0$ $B_2=\omega$ $B_3=0$.."$\omega$" should be in capital letters sorry